# Making template html for json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, templates

I am using  [t.js](https://github.com/jasonmoo/t.js/blob/master/t_test.html) as a template engine in my project. How to make template for this json:

```
{
data: [
    {
        FirstName: "Test1",
        LastName: "Test11"

    },
    {
        FirstName: "Test2",
        LastName: "Test22"
    },
    {
        FirstName: "Test3",
        LastName: "Test33"
    }
]
```

}

I want to render it like

```
<ul>
    <li>Test1,Test11</li>
    <li>Test2,Test22</li>
    <li>Test3,Test33</li>
</ul>
```

Can you suggest any other template engine along with template html for my above case which is better? I don't want to use any template engine using `eval or new Func`

Comment: That isn't JSON. Run it through http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Markup

```
<ul id="myList">
    {{@mydata}} <li>{{=_val.FirstName}},{{=_val.LastName}}</li> {{/@mydata}}
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
var source = $("#myList").html();
var template = new t(source);
$("#myList").html(template.render({
    mydata: [
        {
        FirstName: "Test1",
        LastName: "Test11"

        },
        {
            FirstName: "Test2",
            LastName: "Test22"},
        {
            FirstName: "Test3",
            LastName: "Test33"
        }
    ]
}));
```

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/diode/c2Qhw/